# Sorting in R and Numpy

Tags: python, r, numpy

I am trying to convert some R code into numpy. I have a vector as follows:

```
   r=[2.00000
   1.64000
   1.36000
   1.16000
   1.04000
   1.00000
   1.64000
   1.28000
   1.00000
   0.80000
   0.68000
   0.64000
   1.36000
   1.00000
   0.72000
   0.52000
   0.40000
   0.36000
   1.16000
   0.80000
   0.52000
   0.32000
   0.20000
   0.16000
   1.04000
   0.68000
   0.40000
   0.20000
   0.08000
   0.04000
   1.00000
   0.64000
   0.36000
   0.16000
   0.04000
   0.00000]
```

I am trying to convert following R code

```
index <- order(r)
```

into numpy by following code

```
index = np.argsort(r)
```

Here are the results

Numpy

```
index=array([35, 29, 34, 28, 33, 23, 27, 22, 21, 32, 17, 16, 26, 15, 20, 11, 31,25, 10, 14,  9, 19, 30,  5,  8, 13,  4, 24, 18,  3,  7, 12,  2,  6, 1,  0])
```

R

```
index= [36 30 35 29 24 34 23 28 22 18 33 17 27 16 21 12 32 11 26 15 10 20  6  9 14 31  5 25  4 19  8  3 13  2  7  1]
```

As you see the results are different. How can I obtain results of R in numpy

Comment: Remember that `r` vectors are one-indexed, while `numpy` arrays are 0 indexed.  First verify that you are doing a stable sort in both languages

Comment: I am aware of indexing differences. Look at after fourth element in the results. You can see

Comment: That's the second part of my comment.  Sorts handle ties differently, some are stable (order from the original array is maintained in the case of a tie), others are not.  `argsort` allows you to make use of a stable sort `argsort(r, kind='stable')`.  I don't know enough about `r` to know which algorithm it uses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of [`order`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/order), it looks like `r` uses radix sort for short vectors, which is indeed a stable sort.  [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) on the other hand uses quicksort by default which is *not* a stable sort, and will not guarantee ties to be in the same order as the original array.

However, you can use a stable sort with `argsort` by specifying the `kind` flag:

```
np.argsort(r, kind='stable')
```

When I use a stable sort on your vector:

```
array([35, 29, 34, 28, 23, 33, 22, 27, 21, 17, 32, 16, 26, 15, 20, 11, 31,
       10, 25, 14,  9, 19,  5,  8, 13, 30,  4, 24,  3, 18,  7,  2, 12,  1,
        6,  0], dtype=int64)
```

Compared to the `r` result (subtracting one for the difference in indexing):

```
np.array_equal(np.argsort(r, kind='stable'), r_out - 1)
```

```
True
```

---

**A word of warning**: it appears the `r` switches to shell sort under certain conditions (I don't know enough about `r` to give a more detailed clarification), but shell sort *is not* stable.  This will be something you have to address if those conditions are met.

Comment: You can force `order` to use radix sorting in R with `order(r, method = 'radix')`

Comment: From `?order`:  The
          default (‘"auto"’) implies ‘"radix"’ for short numeric
          vectors, integer vectors, logical vectors and factors.
          Otherwise, it implies ‘"shell"’.

Comment: Short vectors are those with up to 2^31-1 elements ... I don't know the performance implications of using a radix sort on a very long vector ...

Comment: @BenBolker if I had to guess, it comes down to space complexity for very large inputs more than anything else.  Shell sort is O(1) vs O(n + k) for radix sort